# JQuery click listener called too early

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have two simple methods, one to open a menu and one to close a menu.

On a button click the `openmenu` method is called. I then want to add a click listener to everything to the right of the menu, wrapped in a `div` called wrapper. This is only added when the menu is open so it can close. However, since the open menu button is inside the `div` called wrapper, it opens and closes instantly.

I want to open the menu, then once it is open listen for a click, so don't count the first click of it opening.

Below is my code.

```
function openMenu() {
    document.getElementById("sideMenu").style.width = "250px";
    menuOpen = true;

    $("#wrapper").one('click',function(){
       closeMenu();
    });
}

function closeMenu() { //method to close the menu
    document.getElementById("sideMenu").style.width = "0"; //set the width of the menu to 0
    menuOpen=false; //the menu isn't open anymore
    alert();
}
```

Comment: use `e.preventDefualt()` on the openMenu click event.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can stop the `event` from propagating up to the `wrapper`. This will stop the event from bubbling up and any event listeners on `wrapper` will not be called.

```
function openMenu(e) {
    e.stopPropagation();
    document.getElementById("sideMenu").style.width = "250px";
    menuOpen = true;

    $("#wrapper").one('click',function(){
       closeMenu();
    });
}
```

[Reference: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Event/stopPropagation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Event/stopPropagation)

Comment: Okay great thanks that worked, I originally had an "onClick" tag on the div that opened the menu, I had to remove that and use JQuery to listen on the div.

Comment: You can pass the `event` using the `onClick` as well but in my opinion, that is not a great way to do it. What you have finally done sounds great.

Answer (score 0):

You should rearrange your HTML so that `openmenu` button be outside `wrapper` div.

EDIT:
Then try this.

```
$("#wrapper button").click(function() {
    if (menuOpen)
        closeMenu();
    else
        openMenu();
}

function openMenu() {
    document.getElementById("sideMenu").style.width = "250px";
    menuOpen = true;    
}

function closeMenu() { //method to close the menu
    document.getElementById("sideMenu").style.width = "0"; //set the width of the menu to 0
    menuOpen=false; //the menu isn't open anymore    
}
```

Comment: Yes it does work like this but I want it to close if the user clicks on the the openmenu button also. The menu slides out on the left side of the screen, I want everything on the right side, including the open menu controls to be detected.

Answer (score 0):

The click event that opens the menu is bubbling up to the #wrapper element, triggering the closeMenu function.  You can prevent this by using `.stopPropagation()` on the click event, or by returning false from the handler:

```js
function openMenu() {
  document.getElementById("sideMenu").style.width = "250px";

  $("#wrapper").one('click', closeMenu);
  return false; // <-- prevent the click event from bubbling up to #wrapper
}

function closeMenu() { 
  document.getElementById("sideMenu").style.width = "0"; 
}

$('#openTheMenu').on("click", openMenu);
```

```css
#sideMenu {
  border: 1px solid;
  overflow: hidden;
  width: 0;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="wrapper">
  <div id="sideMenu">This is the side menu</div>
  <button id="openTheMenu">Open</button>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Well, lets see. Options, options, so many options! Basic ones:

**1. Open Test**

TEST the state of affair to ascertain the current state of the menu, and bail out if your conditions aren't met:

```
function openMenu() {

    $("#sideMenu").css("width", "250px");

    $("#wrapper").on('click', function(){
       closeMenu();
    });
}

function closeMenu() { //method to close the menu
    let $sMenu = $("#sideMenu")
    if($sMenu.css("width") !== "250px") return false;
    $sMenu.css("width" "0px"); //set the width of the menu to 0
}
```

**2. Append a class [[ NOTE: this is my preferred approach, or this with a hybrid of #3 below ]]**

Since you're using jQuery to handle your targeting anyway, remove the width code entirely, favoring CSS to both maintain MVC and do your lifting. Append the class when open, and, using the  class name to target, strip it to close.

jQuery

```
$("#wrapper").on('click', function(){
   closeMenu();
});

function openMenu(){
   $("#sideMenu").addClass("menuOpen"); 
}

function closeMenu(){
   $(".menuOpen").removeClass("menuOpen"); // Note that this can ONLY TARGET the menu WHEN OPEN 
}
```

CSS

```
#sideMenu { width:0px; }
#sideMenu.menuOpen { width: 250px; }
```

**3. Don't use separate methods**

Use a single function to handle both events:

```
function toggleMenu(forceState=null){
    let $sMenu = "(#sideMenu)";
    if(forceState !== null){ 
        $sMenu.css('width', forceState);
        return;
    }

    let currentMenuWidth = $menuObj.css('width');
    $sMenu.css("width", ($menuObj)=>{return currentMenuWidth=='250px' ? '0px' : '250px');
}
```

**Side Note:** 
`Hide`/`Show`
If you insist on using jQuery, leverage it. it has `hide()` and `show()` methods built right in. Better yet, use `.toggle()` (https://www.w3schools.com/jquery/eff_toggle.asp)